# unpacking records in a postgres array

Tags: postgresql

Given t_my_type defined below and the array packing and unpacking :

```
create type t_my_type as (aa TEXT, bb INTEGER);

with q0 as (
  select 'a' x, 1 y UNION
  select 'b' x, 2 y
),
q1 as (
    select array_agg(distinct(x,y)::t_my_type) a from q0 q
),
q2 as (
    SELECT unnest(q1.a) a from q1
)
SELECT (q.a::t_my_type).aa, (q.a::t_my_type).bb
from q2 q
;
```

I'm wondering if there is 
a more elegant (fewer number of casts) to have the last query :

```
SELECT q.aa, q.bb
```

instead of

```
SELECT (q.a::t_my_type).aa, (q.a::t_my_type).bb
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with q0 as (
  select 'a' x, 1 y union
  select 'b' x, 2 y
),
q1 as (
    select array_agg(distinct(x,y)::t_my_type) a from q0 q
),
q2 as (
    select unnest(q1.a) a from q1
)

select (a).*
from q2;

 aa | bb 
----+----
 a  |  1
 b  |  2
(2 rows)
```

Of course, you can also specify columns explicitly

```
select (a).aa, (a).bb
from q2;
```

Answer (score 1):

here I replace union with values and skip aggregation/unnesting:

```
t=# with a(t_my_type) as (
  values (('a',2)::t_my_type),(('b',1)::t_my_type)
)
select (t_my_type).*
from a;
 aa | bb
----+----
 a  |  2
 b  |  1
(2 rows)
```